# how to transfer files stably in linux

Tags: linux, ssh, file-transfer, rsync, scp

I am trying to transfer large data from windows to linux by using SCP.

```
scp GEOS* username@ip:/path/to/destination
```

It works. But it is pretty slow and the connection would be reset two hours later.

```
files.tar                                                                                                                                                     50% 9109MB   1.1MB/s 2:12:35 ETAConnection reset by IP port 22
files.tar                                                                                                                                                     50% 9109MB   1.0MB/s 2:27:19 ETAlost connection
```

I wonder if there is any another more stable way to achieve it.

And also, I heard that rsync can continue interrupted transfers. I tired

```
rsync -ht --progress --stats  GEOS* /path/to/destination
```

And I tired it again after rebooting my pc. It seems like that I transfer files from zero again.

I wonder how I can continue the interrupted transfer.

Thanks,
Lixu

Comment: You have to use `--append` or `--append-verify` with rsync to make it append to the current version of the file.

Comment: If you have access to the Windows machine, have you tried zipping the `files.tar` file before you try grabbing it from Linux?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>It's tricky to work out what you're actually doing because neither of your quoted example commands is  valid - as written each would either fail or else could not do what you have said it does.</sub>

<sub>I'm going to guess you meant these:</sub>

```
scp GEOS* username@ip:/path/to/destination
rsync -ht --progress --stats GEOS* username@ip:/path/to/destination
```

<sub>If that's not right, please edit your question to show what commands you *actually* tried and I'll see if I can update my answer accordingly.</sub>

---

The `rsync` command works in one of two different ways depending on how it's called.

1. Rsync to two paths that look like they're local.

   ```
   rsync /path/to/source/GEOS* /path/to/destination/
   ```

   This version of the `rsync` command will not be usefully restartable, for two reasons.

   - There is no metadata transferred with the file so `rsync` cannot tell if the file is a likely candidate for a shortcut (use `rsync -a` instead of just `rsync` to fix this).
   - You are using a source and destination path that "looks like" it's local. On this basis `rsync` cannot run as client/server and will not attempt to skip parts of the files that have already been transferred.
2. Rsync between a local and remote host.

   ```
   rsync -ht --progress --stats GEOS* username@ip:/path/to/destination
   ```

   This version of the `rsync` command runs in client/server mode, and because it includes the file timestamps (`-t`), will restart in the event of a network failure.

   Notice the difference between this command (local/remote) and the second reason for #1 failing to be usefully restartable (local/local).

I would not recommend the use of `--append` or `--append-verify` unless you can *absolutely and totally guarantee* that the source file has not changed in any way since the beginning of the first `rsync` attempt. Even then I wouldn't generally recommend it simply because it doesn't really save very much time and it does greatly increase the opportunity for a mis-copy when it's misused. If there is any doubt whatsoever about the file having been changed, using `--append` or one of its variants will guarantee an undetectably wrongly copied file.